# How to adjust darkness of various colors for text

Tags: header-footer, color, margins

#### Question: 1

How can I adjust darkness of different colors in my document?

#### Question: 2

I want to add headrule and footrule with specified width and length, even I wish to write some text at left, center and right header and same things at footer. If I made mistake in defining `geometry` (margin) of document, please guide me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.95} 
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.45cm}
\begin{document}
    \large
\begin{center}
    \textcolor{Magenta}{\textbf{Exercises}} 
\end{center} 
\textcolor{Magenta}{\textbf{Example}}

\textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{Body of question Body of question Body of question Body of question}}

\textcolor{Magenta}{\textbf{Solution}}

\textcolor{Green}{\textbf{Body of solution Body of solution Body of solution Body of solution}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. If you have two different questions, I recommend asking it in two questions instead of combine it.

Comment: Answer for question 1: Try `red` and `red!50!black` (read more [here](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)). Question 2: Have a look at [`fancyhdr`](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)

Comment: @JouleV Ok i will remember this thing next time. Accepting your recommendation. One request to you please explain so i can understand in better way. Surely i will go through the given link.

Comment: I pointed to two links for the two questions respectively. Reading them (the manual) is the best way to understand, and the manuals are better than any answers.

Comment: Let me try. But still waiting for solution from somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `xcolor` ([here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)) and `fancyhdr` ([here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)) will help you customise things further, but this will get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{LeftHeader}
\chead{CentreHeader}
\rhead{RightHeader}
\lfoot{LeftFooter}
\cfoot{CentreFooter}
\rfoot{RightFooter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section*{Question 1}

\subsection*{Shades}

\textcolor{magenta}{magenta} \\
\textcolor{magenta!90!black}{magenta!90!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!80!black}{magenta!80!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!70!black}{magenta!70!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!60!black}{magenta!60!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!50!black}{magenta!50!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!40!black}{magenta!40!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!30!black}{magenta!30!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!20!black}{magenta!20!black} \\
\textcolor{magenta!10!black}{magenta!10!black} \\
\textcolor{black}{black}

\subsection*{Tints}

\textcolor{magenta}{magenta} \\
\textcolor{magenta!90!white}{magenta!90!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!80!white}{magenta!80!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!70!white}{magenta!70!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!60!white}{magenta!60!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!50!white}{magenta!50!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!40!white}{magenta!40!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!30!white}{magenta!30!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!20!white}{magenta!20!white} \\
\textcolor{magenta!10!white}{magenta!10!white} \\
\textcolor{white}{white}

\section*{Question 2}

Add this to your preamble:

\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{LeftHeader}
\chead{CentreHeader}
\rhead{RightHeader}
\lfoot{LeftFooter}
\cfoot{CentreFooter}
\rfoot{RightFooter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot...how to set margin of header and footers

Comment: @snehal, the `geometry` package will let you set all margins. This site works best if you ask specific questions. I suggest you ask a new question with an appropriate minimal working example asking exactly what you want.